# PHP foreach loop doesn't pass although data in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a weird issue with my PHP script. I have an array $keys that is defined at the beginning of the script:

```
$keys = array("name","date","event","location","address","description","link","linkname");
```

at some point later on I'm looping through the array, trying to print the keys:

```
foreach ($keys as $key_show) {
    echo ($key_show);
}
```

And nothing is actually printed. I put a var_dump($keys) before the loop, and it seems the array is still populated with the entries from above at this point in the script. Interestingly, as soon as I put the var_dump there, the keys also showed up in the foreach-loop.

Full script can be see [here](https://gist.github.com/interference/5332641)

Comment: If you test the assignment and the `foreach` loop in succession, it works correctly and shows all values. There must be something between the assignment and the loop, causing your problem.

Comment: That's what I thought, hence the check with var_dump. The array is still in the old state, right up to the foreach loop and also inside the loop. At least that's what var_dump displays.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, swap the `foreach` for a `while`. I had this issue a little while ago, and for some bizarre reason it worked in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your link

```
} elseif (isset($_POST['editconfirm'])) {
    ...
    if ($jsonConcerts) {
        echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"edit.php\"";
        //var_dump($keys);
        foreach ($keys as $key_show) {
            echo ($key_show. ": ");
            //echo "<input class=\"wide\" name=\"".$key.
            //"\" value=\"".$jsonConcerts[$counter][$key]."\"><br>\n";
        }
        ...
```

You don't close the `form` tag, so all `$key_show` values are treated as attributes of the `form` tag and thus never show up in your html output.

If you run this script on the command line, you will see the array values with or without the `var_dump()`.

Comment: Yes! That's it. The devil's in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Besides, why you use echo "string" and echo ("string") all mixed?

Try without brackets?

```
foreach ($keys as $key_show) {
    echo $key_show;
}
```

Comment: I know, but why use them in one line and not the other? I never use them [or would use them always the other way round].